# Removing upvote (unupvote) on documentation example reduces rep of contributors, but doesn't reset rep cap

Tags: bug, reputation, documentation

If I upvote an example and remove the upvote 20 times, the guys that earn rep will earn 0 in total, but their rep cap will be reached. I ran into this problem now, got 10 upvotes and 5 removed their upvotes. After that 50 more guys voted the example up, but I still got only 150 rep today:

[image]